# SQL select statement with a quotename removing the last character on the last row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `select` statement that uses `QUOTNAME` to add single quotes and a comma to each of the results.

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(field1,'''')+',' AS [1]
```

Which changes the results from this.

```
  1
11111
22222
33333
44444
```

To this

```
   1
'11111',
'22222',
'33333',
'44444',
```

However I would like to know if it is possible to remove the comma from the very last row? Too look like this.

```
   1
'11111',
'22222',
'33333',
'44444'
```

edit: I should have mentioned this is a View

Comment: If your making a CSV presumably you will have to iterate the returned rows in the client to write the file. If so, thats the place to add the chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(field1,'''')+
   case when row_number() over(order by (select 1))= 
   count(*) over () then '' else ',' end AS [1]
FROM <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @count int
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM my_table
SELECT QUOTENAME(field1, '''') + CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY field1) < @count THEN ',' ELSE '' END AS [1]
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Ok, you should be using CTE then. The answer from AeroX should do what you need

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to say that SQL is the wrong place to be formatting your data and that it should be done in your application or client.

But as you've asked it is possible and this is one way of doing it:

```
WITH
  MyData AS (
    SELECT
      field1,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY field1 DESC) AS rowNo
    FROM Data
  )
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    QUOTENAME( field1, '''' ),
    (CASE WHEN rowNo <> 1 THEN ',' END)
  ) AS [1]
FROM MyData
ORDER BY rowNo DESC;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/60bab/4/0)